# Show that if $ \theta: R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism, then $\theta$ is one-to-one provided it is onto.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a division ring and $S \neq \{0\}$ be a ring. Show that if $ \theta: R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism, then $\theta$ is one-to-one provided it is onto.

Proof: Assume, by way of contradiction, that $\theta$ is not one-to-one. Since $\theta$ is onto, there exists $s\in S$ and $r_1,r_2 \in R$ with $r_1 \neq r_2 $ and $r_1 \theta=s=r_2 \theta$.

Let $r_0=r_1-r_2 \neq 0$. Since $R$ is a division ring, $\exists y_0 \in R$ such that $y_0r_0=1$. Let $r \in R$, then $r \theta=(r \times 1)\theta=(r\theta)(1 \theta)=(r\theta)(y_0r_0 \theta)=(r \theta)(y_0\theta)(r_0 \theta)$

$r \theta=(r_1-r_2)\theta=r_1\theta-r_2\theta=0$

So, $(r \theta)(y_0\theta)(r_0 \theta)=0$ which implies that $0 \in S.$ However, $S \neq \{0\}$

Are there any problems with this proof? Any criticism would be appreciated.

Comment: $0 \in S$ does not cause any contradiction!

Comment: Hints to a correct proof: Introducing $y_0$ is a good idea. You want to show $1 = 0$ in $S$. The condition that $\theta$ be onto is useless, as far as showing the injectivity of $\theta$ is required.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Are you sure about that second part? It was made very clear to me that the onto part of this question was needed.

Comment: If you define rings to be nonunital, then yes, it's needed. But with the standard definition nowadays, it isn't.

Comment: @darijgrinberg We do use the nonunion definition of rings. I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is right. We have $$1\theta=(y_{0}r_{0})\theta=y_{0}(r_{1}-r_{2})\theta=(y_{0}\theta)(r_{1}-r_{2})\theta=(y_{0}\theta)(r_{1}\theta-r_{2}\theta)=(y_{0}\theta)(s-s)=0.$$

Now, $r\theta=(r.1)\theta=(r\theta)(1\theta)=(r\theta)0=0$, for every $r\in R$ and so $S=\{0\}$, contradiction. Hence, $\theta$ is one-to-one.

Comment: Thank you. I think my wording towards the end was poorly written. I'll structure my answer like you have.

Answer (score 1):

No, your attempt at a proof is incorrect: concluding $0\in S$ is obviously not a contradiction. But it can be fixed: if $1\theta=0$, then $r\theta=0$ for every $r\in R$.

---

More simply, recall that the kernel of a ring homomorphism is an ideal. What are the ideals of a division ring?

We can note that the “onto” hypothesis is not necessary, it just suffices that $R\theta\ne\{0\}$, for, in this case, $\ker\theta\ne R$.

If your ring homomorphisms are required to map $1$ into $1$ the condition is for free. The hypothesis that $\theta$ is onto and $S\ne\{0\}$ also guarantees the condition.